# NoReverseMatch at /notes/create/ Reverse for 'notes_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notes/list/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I don't know how can i add link of user notes list in side bar.

the error is coming in the given following lines of template

pages/base_stuff/side_bar.html. I want to add link in the given template so that i can redirect user to the usernotes_list template

```
 <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="{%url 'notes:notes_list' notes.author.username %}">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Your Notes</span> 
              </a>
 </li>
```

notes/urls.py

```
app_name = 'notes'

urlpatterns = [
  
    path('list/<str:username>',views.NotesListView.as_view(),name='notes_list'),

]
```

notes/views.py

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes_data'
    # paginate_by = 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(auth.models.User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Notes.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-create_date')
```

notes/models.py

```
class Notes(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    essay = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("notes:notes_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

pages/base_stuff/side_bar.html

```
{% load static %}
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
              <img src="{{ user.userprofile.avatar.url }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
              <p>{{ user.username }}</p>

              <a href="#">{% if user.is_active %}<i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online {% else %}<i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Offline {% endif %}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- search form -->
          <!-- /.search form -->
          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="{% url 'test' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Home</span> 
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
               <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Courses</span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{% url 'videos:videos_playlist' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Videos</span> 
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="{%url 'notes:notes_create'%}">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Create Note</span> 
              </a>
            </li>
             <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="{%url 'notes:notes_list' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Your Notes</span> 
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="{%url 'quiz:home'%}">
                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Quiz</span>
              </a>  
            </li>
          {% if user.is_superuser %}
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Admin</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}

            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="{% url 'about' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>About</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="pages/calendar.html">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Contact</span>
              </a>
            </li> 
        </section>
```

Comment: what is `notes.author.username` can your share your models and full template ?

Comment: i can share model but template is quite hard cause that is every long but still I am sharing if that is really useful

Comment: template is essential...

Comment: I have add that You can see in my question

Comment: @FlashMaddy I suppose you want to show the current logged in user's notes list from your sidebar ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes! exactly I am trying to do this. I am literally tired of trying to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed argument the line where you used that link. So do:

```
<li class="active treeview">
    <a href="{% url 'notes:notes_list' user.username %}">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style='font-weight: normal;'>Your Notes</span> 
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I have ask new question ,can you answer that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303253/generic-detail-view-userprofiledetailview-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-p/64310557?noredirect=1#comment113748471_64310557)

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments, If you want to show the current user's notes list in your template then you can try like this.

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes_data'
    # paginate_by = 
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-create_date')
```

Now you don't need to pass the extra username parameter from your url

```
path('list/user/notes/',views.NotesListView.as_view(),name='notes_list'),
```

And the url in the template

```
   <a href="{% url 'notes:notes_list' %}">
```

Comment: Nice this is really nice way to do so. I was literally finding something useful way to do that thing and you just shared it thank you @arjun.

Comment: btw @arjun can you tell me how can i count list item with particular user ?

Comment: I am trying following lines and it is giving me total number of objects in notes model. I just want to count the person how is login can see the number of his notes in home page. `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_count"] = User.objects.count()`

Comment: @FlashMaddy In your template you can do `{{notes_data.count}}`

Comment: I know this way. by this way i can count items on note list template but i want to show that count on the home page template. How can I count them on home template ?

Comment: try this . `{{request.user.notes_set.all.count}}`

Comment: Nice! It worked . Can you explain me what notes_set is and where from you call it ?

Comment: @FlashMaddy Here the User model does not have an explicit reference to the Notes model so django automatically adds a reverse-reference, which is by default `modelname_set`. You can override this by using the `related_name` on the model. see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for more detail

Comment: I have ask new question please check if you know the solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303253/generic-detail-view-userprofiledetailview-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-p/64310557?noredirect=1#comment113748471_64310557)