# Generic detail view UserProfileDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Well I am facing error and it's now its been two days to this question and still stuck on this mistake, anybody can help and able to fix this. I am new in Django and need help. I shall be thankful. If any thing else requires for answers than tell me I will update my questions with that detail..
models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
   


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):

    model = UserProfile
    template_name = "profiles/userprofile_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs) 
            is_following = False
            if self.object.user in self.request.user.userprofile.follower.all():
                is_following = True
            context["is_following"] = is_following
            return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('user',UserProfileCreateView.as_view(template_name = 'profiles/userprofile.html'),name='home')
    # path('user/',userprofile,name = 'home'),
     path('user-profile/',UserProfileFollowToggle.as_view(),name = 'toggle'),
    path('<str:username>/',UserProfileDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
]
```

userprofile_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="{{ object.user.userprofile.avatar.url }}" width = "50%"></p>
{{ request.user.userprofile.follower.all }}<br>
{{object.user.userprofile }}
{% if object.user in request.user.userprofile.follower.all  %}
Following
{% endif %}
<p>{% include 'profiles/snippets/follow_toggle.html' with username=user.username is_following=is_following %}</p>
<h2>{{ object.username }}</h2>
/{{is_following}} 
{% endblock content %}
```

snippets/follow_toggle.html

```
<form class='form' method='POST' action="{% url 'profiles:toggle'%}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='username' value="{% if username %}{{ username }}{% else %}hello{% endif %}">
<button class='btn {% if is_following %}btn-warning{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %}'>{% if is_following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}</button>
</form>
```

error traceback:

```
  Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/testuser/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 106, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 45, in get_object
    raise AttributeError(

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profiles/testuser/
Exception Value: Generic detail view UserProfileDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of your User model as well please?

Comment: I am using django built in user model from `djnago.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant the UserProfile model. In this case I'm assuming UserProfile has a OneToOne `user` relationship to a `User` instance?  If so take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ and how the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception is caught.

Comment: yes userprofile has one to one relation with user model

Comment: There you go then. You probably created the UserProfile instance without setting a relationship for `user`. I'd suggest making this a non-nullable field (`null=False, blank=False`) to prevent this from happening - a UserProfile without User doesn't really make sense does it?

Comment: Now there is an other exception which is :Generic detail view UserProfileDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: Can you add the **`UserProfile`** model? @FlashMaddy

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have add that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

1. `str` type used instead of `slug` type in urls.py
2. `UserProfileDetailView` doesn't specify your custom `slug_url_kwarg` and `slug_field`
3. `UserProfileDetailView` specifies `UserProfile` model but `UserProfile` model doesn't have attribute or method `username`, which is on `User table.

## Solution

Reading Django's DetailView code, you'll find that the following is necessary to get your code working properly.

### Update class attributes

views.py

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    slug_url_kwarg = "username"
    slug_field = "username"
```

### Update UserProfile model OR Update UserProfileDetailView.get_slug_field

`UserProfile is the lookup table defined for UserProfileDetailView and` get_slug_field`method, which reads`slug_field`property on the UserProfileDetailView doesn't support dot syntax method traversal (ie:`user.username`).
Thus either:

1. UserProfile model must have reference to `username` or;
2. `get_slug_field` must explicitly define slug field or;
3. `get_slug_field` must add functionality for dot syntax method traversal

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.model):
    ...
    
    @property
    def username(self):
        self.user.username
```

OR

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get_slug_field(self):
        self.user.username
```

### Update username type in urls.py

Helpful, but not necessary.

urls.py

```
path('<slug:username>/', UserProfileDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
```

## References

Django Detail View `get_slug_field` (Github): https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L78-L80

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the user pk or slug in the url so that django can retrieve the user using this pk or slug
so edit the url to be like this

```
path('<slug:username>/',UserProfileDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
```

but make sure that your slug equal the username of the user , to do this override the save method in your model to be like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.slug = self.username
    super(Your_Model_Name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

make sure to change 'Your_Model_Name' with your model class name

Comment: and how can i set slug equal to username ?

Comment: Do I have to add this in models?

Comment: yes you need to add this method I you model after the model fields and make sure to change the 'your model name' to your model name , after this when you create a new user the slug filed will get the value of the username automatically

Comment: Unnecessarily duplicating data across tables compromises data integrity and adds maintenance overhead. Just create a class property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set [**`slug_url_kwarg`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) and [**`slug_field`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) attributes on your view class

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    slug_url_kwarg = "username" # this the `argument` in the URL conf
    slug_field = "your_model_field" # this is the model field name.

    # Rest of your code
```

Comment: I did that but now it showing me :ValueError at /profiles/testuser/

Field 'id' expected a number but got 'testuser'.

Comment: What was the `slug_field` value you have provided? Add the complete error  traceback. @FlashMaddy

Comment: This isn't entirely sufficient since username exists on User model not UserProfile model

Comment: That's what the `slug_field` attribute does. You can set it as appropriate *span field* (using double underscore) @pygeek